# Merge multiple rows into one?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have one stage table '`STAGE_TABLE`' which includes following values (columns are varchar2 except ids) -

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
¦  STAGE_ID ¦ EMP_ID     ¦ ATTR1_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR1_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR2_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR2_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR3_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR3_NEW_VAL ¦
¦-----------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------¦
¦         1 ¦       E001 ¦ xyz           ¦ pqr           ¦ mmm           ¦ nnn           ¦ zzz           ¦ aaa           ¦
¦         2 ¦       E001 ¦               ¦               ¦               ¦               ¦               ¦               ¦
¦         3 ¦       E001 ¦ pqr           ¦ abc           ¦ xxx           ¦ yyy           ¦               ¦               ¦
¦         4 ¦       E002 ¦ aaa           ¦ ccc           ¦ bbb           ¦ ttt           ¦               ¦               ¦
¦         5 ¦       E002 ¦               ¦               ¦               ¦               ¦ fff           ¦ ppp           ¦
¦         6 ¦       E002 ¦               ¦               ¦ kkk           ¦ jjj           ¦               ¦               ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to merge multiple rows from above table belonging to same employee into one -

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
¦ EMP_ID     ¦ ATTR1_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR1_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR2_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR2_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR3_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR3_NEW_VAL ¦
¦------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------¦
¦       E001 ¦ pqr           ¦ abc           ¦ xxx           ¦ yyy           ¦ zzz           ¦ aaa           ¦
¦       E002 ¦ aaa           ¦ ccc           ¦ kkk           ¦ jjj           ¦ fff           ¦ ppp           ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I came to know about MERGE statement but not sure if it will work.
I am new to oracle pl/sql.

Comment: What do you mean saying "merge"? What would be your result depending on given data?

Comment: because i am merging data from multiple columns into single row.

Comment: To understand your question: Why is ATTR1_OLD_VAL = pqr and not xyz? Because STAGE_ID=3 > STAGE_ID=1 ?

Comment: yes... consider stage table is a log table. stage id represents unique log id. if value is empty that means now change were made at that time for given attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tmp 
  ( 
     row_id NUMBER, 
     id     NUMBER, 
     t1     VARCHAR2(5), 
     t2     VARCHAR2(5), 
     t3     VARCHAR2(5) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO tmp 
VALUES      (1, 
             1, 
             'a', 
             NULL, 
             'a'); 

INSERT INTO tmp 
VALUES      (2, 
             1, 
             NULL, 
             'b', 
             'b'); 

INSERT INTO tmp 
VALUES      (3, 
             1, 
             'c', 
             NULL, 
             NULL); 

INSERT INTO tmp 
VALUES      (1, 
             2, 
             'a', 
             'a', 
             NULL); 

INSERT INTO tmp 
VALUES      (2, 
             2, 
             NULL, 
             'b', 
             NULL);
```

So, we should get: 1,C,B,B and 2,A,B,NULL:

```
select id_merged, T1,T2,T3 from 
( SELECT id id_merged,
 first_value(T1 IGNORE nulls) over (partition BY id ORDER BY row_id DESC) T1,
 first_value(T2 IGNORE nulls) over (partition BY id ORDER BY row_id DESC) T2,
 first_value(T3 IGNORE nulls) over (partition BY id ORDER BY row_id DESC) T3,
 rank () over (partition by id order by row_id) rn
FROM tmp)
where rn=1 ORDER BY id_merged;
```

Comment: +1 for nice and concise solution! @Parag will obviously have to `partition by EMP_ID ORDER BY stage_id)`. Why do you `ORDER BY id_merged`?

Comment: I do the order by because it's easier when I check my solutions. :p

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `group by emp_id` and choose a value for attributes using `keep dense_rank`:

```
select 
  emp_id,
  max(ATTR1_OLD_VAL) keep (dense_rank first order by decode(ATTR1_OLD_VAL,null,1,0), stage_id desc) as ATTR1_OLD_VAL
from STAGE_TABLE
group by emp_id;
```

`order by decode(ATTR1_OLD_VAL,null,1,0)` put null values to the end. From those with non-null values choose the latest with `stage_id desc`.

I've put a single attribute you should put the others.